# class pointer method crashing program

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am trying to make a program that has two account balances, one for a go-card the other for a bank account. I have made a `class` for each, however when I try to call the debit method in the go-card `class` via a class pointer, my program crashes (it compiles with no errors).

The **GoCardAccount.cpp** file:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "GoCardAccount.hpp"
#include "BankAccount.hpp"

GoCardAccount::GoCardAccount(long initialamount, BankAccount(ba)) {
    balance = initialamount;
}

bool GoCardAccount::trip(long amount) {
    LOW_LIMIT = 1000;
    TOP_UP = 5000;

    if(balance >= amount) {
        balance -= amount;

        if(balance < LOW_LIMIT) {
            if(ba->debit(TOP_UP)) {
                printf("Balance fallen below minimum, "
                    "topped up $50 to go card account.\n");
                balance += TOP_UP;
                return true;
            }   
            else {
                printf("Your balance has gone below minimum amount, however "
                    "there are insufficient funds in bank account to top up.\n");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

long GoCardAccount::getBalance()  {
    return balance;
}
```

**GoCardAccount.hpp** file:

```
class BankAccount;
class GoCardAccount {
    long balance;
    BankAccount *ba;
    long LOW_LIMIT;
    long TOP_UP;

public:
    GoCardAccount(long amount, BankAccount(ba));
    bool trip(long amount);
    long getBalance();
};
```

The debit method from **BankAccount.cpp**:

```
bool BankAccount::debit(long amount1) {
    if(amount1 >=0 && amount1 <= balance) {
        balance -= amount1;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The start of the `main` function where I initialise the classes:

```
int main(void) {
    long startamount;
    long gocardamount;

    printf("Input initial bank balance: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &startamount);
    BankAccount ba(startamount);

    printf("Input initial Go-Card balance: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &gocardamount);
    GoCardAccount gca(gocardamount, ba);
}
```

Comment: You say you don't get any errors when building (otherwise you could not run the program so that's pretty obvious), but do you get any *warnings*? Even if you enable more warnings? How about the crash itself, where does it happen? You *have* tried locating it by running your program in a debugger?

Comment: A hint though: You never make the member variable `GoCardAccount::ba` point anywhere.

Comment: I get no warning messages, I know the crash happens at "if(ba->debit(TOP_UP))"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now you are trying to call `ba` method, but `BankAccount *ba;` is not even itinialized.

You have to pass a pointer on `BankAccount` to `GoCardAccount` ctor. So change this line (in main)

```
GoCardAccount gca(gocardamount, ba);
```

to

```
GoCardAccount gca(gocardamount, &ba);
```

and in `GoCardAccount` (GoCardAccount.cpp) change ctor from

```
GoCardAccount::GoCardAccount(long initialamount, BankAccount(ba))
{
    balance = initialamount;
}
```

to

```
GoCardAccount::GoCardAccount(long initialamount, BankAccount * pba) : 
balance (initialamount), ba(pba) {}
```

---

The argument

```
BankAccount(ba)
```

won't store argument passed to ctor to `ba`, it means that argument passed in function call, which will be placed on stack, will has identifier `ba`.

- You should use different name than member variable
- It **has** to be pointer (in your case)
- In member initialize list you have to assign this value to member variable

Example

```
GoCardAccount::GoCardAccount(long initialamount, BankAccount * pba) : balance (initialamount), ba(pba) {}
```

Comment: I was typing and I didn't refresh , I removed my post. But it would be nice to mention why `BankAccount(ba)` in constructor argument is _ok_( compiles) , as I think OP feels he/she has initialized it.

Comment: What is pba? Just an extra pointer for use in the GoCardAccount.cpp file?

Comment: No its name of an argument which ctor accepts. Same as `long initialamount`. It should has different name then member variable. Same as i did.

Comment: How am I supposed to initialise BankAccount if I don't have access to the bank account balance in the GoCardAccount.cpp file? (The initialamount is for the gocard's balance not the bankaccount). Also, I feel like my tutor doesnt want me to use functions we have not been taught (pba). Is there any other way?

Comment: You have pointer on `BankAccount` instance as member variable of class `GoCardAccount` named `ba`. You will initialize that variable in `GoCardAccount` ctor, to which you have to pass address of existing `BankAccount` instance. I wrote that code in my answer, just replace it... I will write what exactly you have to replace.

Comment: Do I need to change the header file too? I am getting errors now: http://imgur.com/a/VhxCH

Comment: Yes in `GoCardAccount.hpp` change  `GoCardAccount(long amount, BankAccount(ba));` to `GoCardAccount(long amount, BankAccount * pba);` :-)

Comment: I am still getting errors, do I need to change the main.cpp file too?http://imgur.com/a/eT3Bb

Comment: Oh i told you to change it. Read my comment again and _carefully_ please :-)

Comment: Oh right at the start haha, my bad. It is working now, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For first let's talk about your constructor of `class GoCardAccount`, because there is a term used by [Scott Meyers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Meyers) in *Effective STL* (2001) book, which is the [**most vexing parse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse):

```
GoCardAccount(long amount, BankAccount(ba));
```

The code snippet above will declare a constructor which takes two parameters:

1. The `long amount` parameter is named `amount`, and it's type is `long`. This is fine.
2. The `BankAccount(ba)` parameter is named `ba`, and it's type is `BankAccount`, because the parentheses around `ba` are superfluous and are ignored.

So, the declaration above is same as:

```
GoCardAccount(long amount, BankAccount ba);
```

This isn't what you want, because the second parameter will take a `BankAccount` instance by value and you need a pointer to it. So, you have to change it to:

```
GoCardAccount(long amount, BankAccount* ba);
```

Change its definition as well and initialize your `BankAccount* ba` member as follows (or use the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)):

```
GoCardAccount::GoCardAccount(long initialamount, BankAccount* ba_ptr) {
    balance = initialamount;
    ba = ba_ptr;
}
```

Comment: @FilipKočica, this site is not only about helping the questioner only but helping the other users as well coming here with similar issues. This is the reason I added another answer with extra informations.

Comment: Ofc i get it, the first part is OK, i just dont know why you are writing what should he change in code since i already wrote it and he solved it. :-)

Comment: @FilipKočica, similar responses ensures the visitors which way to go, there is nothing wrong with them. Moreover I prefer writing complete answers as the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) suggest.

Comment: Ok i just thought its redundant :-)